# Improve postgresql search query

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, knex.js

First of all, I am not sure if the question title is too generic for the question or shall I change it.

Anyway, How can I further improve my PostgreSQL query in order to show the better search result based on the keywords entered?

The current query only works fine if you start your search by searching the `name` first. However, the search breaks and give unexpected results if try to enter any other keywords followed by the name.

```
async getProducts(opts) {
    const query = knex
      .select(
        'id',
        'pharmacy_id',
        'name',
        'ean_code',
        'product_number',
        'strength',
        'dosage_format',
        'packaging_qty',
        'prescription_med',
        'selling_permit_owner',
        'status'
      )
      .from('product')
      .orderBy('id', 'asc');

    return camelizeKeys(await queryWithFilters(query, opts));
  }



const queryWithFilters = (query, opts) =>
  productOpts.reduce((q, opt) => {
    let result;
    const option = opts[opt];

    if (option) {
      if (opt.match(/searchText/)) {
        const regexp = `(${option
      .trim()
      .replace(/\s{1,}/, '|')
      .toLowerCase()})`;
        result = q.where(function() {
          this.where(knex.raw('name ~* ?', regexp))
            .orWhere(knex.raw('strength ~* ?', regexp))
            .orWhere(knex.raw('dosage_format ~* ?', regexp))
            .orWhere(knex.raw('packaging_qty ~* ?', regexp))
            .orWhere(knex.raw('selling_permit_owner ~* ?', regexp));
        });
      }
    }

    return result || q;
  }, query);
```

This is how I render the options on the client side

```
productOptions = () => {
    const { products } = this.props;
    return products.edges.map(({ node }) => {
      const { id, name, strength, dosageFormat, packagingQty } = node;
      return (
        <Option
          key={id}
          value={`${id}`}
          render={`${name}, ${strength}, ${dosageFormat}, ${packagingQty}`}
          style={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #DCDCDC' }}
        >
          {name} {strength} {dosageFormat} {packagingQty}
        </Option>
      );
    });
  };
```

I am a bit stuck on how to further improve the query to make it more lenient and gives more appropriate results.

First - Here typing `burana` gives all the results from the DB which is fine.

[image]

Second - If I try to find the record with `burana 400` it does not resurns the expected result as you can see from the first screenshot.

[image]

Third - Typing `400 burana` should also show the appropriate search result but it doesn't in my current query.

[image]

Comment: You should enable logging and look at the postgres log file to see what query has been generated. It looks to me like when you supply multiple words, it ORs them together (orWhere), hence you get results where it matches 400 but not burana. Bear in mind I know nothing about knex so could be misreading it.

Comment: You should consider using postgres full test search or trigram search features or even better to use external service like elastic search for indexing searchable content.